# Handling collisions in a component entity system approach

Tags: components, entity, system

I'm probably over-thinking this, I'll get that out of the way up-front. But I can't seem to find a good example of a simple collision approach that handles changing the velocity of an entity when it runs into something. What comes to mind initially is having 3 systems, that run in order:

1. MovementSystem (update an entity's position component based on its velocity component)
2. InputSystem (update an entity's velocity component based on input from mouse/keyboard)
3. CollisionSystem (change an entity's velocity component based on whether it's intersecting with another entity)

But isn't there a catch-22 here? If I'm already collided with another entity, now I can't get away, because the collision system keeps killing my velocity. Or do I need to make the collision system understand about the direction of velocity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that will depend on how elastic the collision is, take a look at this: [Elastic Collision Reponse in a Game](http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?t=451345).

Perhaps this post can also help you: [https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/27508/how-will-the-velocities-of-two-moving-objects-change-once-they-collide).

Answer (score 0):

A simple collision system needs to know the angle your object came in at and send it out in the opposite direction. This means rotating the velocity vector by 180° say from 0,1 to 0,-1. To avoid re-collision you need to ensure it "hops" out of collision range before the next tick so you would apply the new velocity to the object's position (p2 = p1*velocity*tick).